# Atomicity of write in Mongo db

Tags: mongodb

Mongo documentation says single document write are atomic but at another place it mentions interleaved transactions may read uncommitted data and before the writer thread has returned.

I understand that other transactions can read uncommitted data because the write may not be still committed to the journal.

But how can threads read data while the writer thread has not returned. Is it for cases when the write concern is not default?

Thanks
Ankur

Comment: Can you reference the places where you read this so we can get some context?

Comment: Hi @Sammaye I am referring to Read Isolation Behavior section in MongDB documentation. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/

Answer (score 2):

Ok with the reference I can now get a context and tell you what this is about.

> Mongo documentation says single document write are atomic

Yep

> it mentions interleaved transactions may read uncommitted

Infact any read may get uncommited data. This is because MongoDB will write to the fsync queue BEFORE it writes to disk.

MongoDB can read from this fsync queue before it goes to disk, and quoting the page:

> Other database systems refer to these isolation semantics as read uncommitted.

Mainly ACID databases do.

> But how can threads read data while the writer thread has not returned.

Thanks to MongoDBs con-currency rules: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#does-a-read-or-write-operation-ever-yield-the-lock

In short, to sum up: The write will not take exclusive lock for the duration of its running, instead it can subside (due to various rules) to a read allowing you to return data half way through a write.

This is also why you must sometimes be careful about multi-document updates and other threads of your application reading data, it may actually get one half of data that is upto date and the other half which is not.

Comment: Thank you Sammaye. But I am still not very clear. I want to understand in context of just one writer thread which is writing just one document. So as far as I understand, that writer thread would write to fsync queue and return and all this is atomic, so how can reader threads read that change before the thread has returned?

Comment: @Ankur because it is a separate thread, the writer thread, as dictated in the documentation can subside half way through a write for the reader thread, as such the reader thread can actually return before the writer thread has returned back to its original thread

Comment: Thank you Sammaye. I was somehow equating atomicity to getting a exclusive lock which is not correct. So my bad. Thanks!!

Comment: @Ankur it does per document just not like SQL, over an entire transaction, so in theory single document writes cannot return before they are done, but multi documents can